# Why the divergent series are acceptables in mathematics?

Tags: divergent-series, zeta-functions

I noticed Euler did solve zeta(2) by the divergent series, and he did break the acceptable limits in his famous proof to get $ ζ(2)= {π² \over 6}$.

Any rigorous proof to make the divergent series a valid method to solve really the mathematics problems?

Comment: Divergent series are not valid. What is valid : the [summation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) (different from the usual one, thus giving different results), the formal series manipulations (when achieved in appropriate setting, for example the ring of formal power series), all the tools coming from complex analysis (analytic continuation)

Comment: [Divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) is as perfectly well-defined as convergent series, and hence acceptable. What is not well-defined is its sum (in the usual sense). But one can prove perfectly valid theorems based on some series being divergent, for example. As for Euler's manipulations, there are valid modern techniques that grew out of his line of thought, such as [zeta-regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization), alternative summation methods, and even nonstandard analysis that makes sense of why his manipulations worked.

Comment: I have a big problem what concern $ ζ(2)= {π² \over 6}$, I want a rigorous proof because divergent series that Euler did use to find ${π² \over 6}$ is not valid at the start. What is the proof what make his start with a divergent series a valid method?